# Multi Select Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

I am developing an MVC App using EF, Code First & C#.  I would like to create an object in my database that stores a list of other objects. i.e. I have an object called PayCodes that lists all the paycodes and another that lists CombinedPayCodes.  The CombinedPayCodes will include 2 or more of the PayCodes from the PayCodes Object.

I can create this relationship easily enough that provides for selecting one pay code but not many pay codes.

Can someone provide some guidance on the best way to achieve this.

```
 public class PayCode
{
    public virtual int PayCodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CombinedPayCode
{
    public virtual int CombinedPayCodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual int PayCodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual PayCode PayCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change property PayCode to ICollection, and add one property CombinedPayCode; that would be create the relationship one to many.

```
public class PayCode
{
  public virtual int PayCodeId { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual CombinedPayCode CombinedPayCode {get;set;}
}

public class CombinedPayCode
{
  public virtual int CombinedPayCodeId { get; set; }
  public virtual int PayCodeId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<PayCode> PayCodes { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi That does not seem to work.  It compiles OK, but neither in the database or the UI does it allow you to select multiple PayCodeId's in the CombinedPay Code.